# Неверно создаются связи в java

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

Имеется JSON:

```
{
   "truckNumber":"test",
   "comments":"test",
   "activity":"hello",
   "updateMode" : "-",
   "carrierName":"test",
   "truckType":"inbound",
   "trailerNumber":" ",
   "carrierCode":"Code",
   "driverName":" ",
   "reference" : "testTrip000",
   "orders":[
      {
         "reference":"ST00013246_40537",
         "cargo":[
            {
               "cargoNumber":"55522532913"
            },
            {
               "cargoNumber":"55522532914"
            },
            {
               "cargoNumber":"55522532915"
            },
            {
               "cargoNumber":"55522532916"
            },
            {
               "cargoNumber":"55522532876"
            },
            {
               "cargoNumber":"55522532877"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "reference":"ST00013246_20849",
         "cargo":[
            {
               "cargoNumber":"55522543768"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "reference":"LO0605269",
         "cargo":[
            {
               "cargoNumber":"84642134"
            },
            {
               "cargoNumber":"84642141"
            },
            {
               "cargoNumber":"84642158"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "reference":"LO0620165",
         "cargo":[
            {
               "cargoNumber":"84642165"
            },
            {
               "cargoNumber":"84642172"
            },
            {
               "cargoNumber":"84642189"
            },
            {
               "cargoNumber":"84642196"
            },
            {
               "cargoNumber":"84642202"
            },
            {
               "cargoNumber":"84642219"
            },
            {
               "cargoNumber":"84642226"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "reference":"LO0606854",
         "cargo":[
            {
               "cargoNumber":"84642233"
            },
            {
               "cargoNumber":"84642240"
            },
            {
               "cargoNumber":"84642257"
            },
            {
               "cargoNumber":"84642264"
            },
            {
               "cargoNumber":"84642271"
            },
            {
               "cargoNumber":"84642288"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "reference":"CHK-275696",
         "cargo":[
            {
               "cargoNumber":"84491350"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "reference":"ST00012903_20849",
         "cargo":[
            {
               "cargoNumber":"55522543769"
            },
            {
               "cargoNumber":"55522543770"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "reference":"LO0606863",
         "cargo":[
            {
               "cargoNumber":"84645814"
            },
            {
               "cargoNumber":"84645821"
            },
            {
               "cargoNumber":"84645838"
            },
            {
               "cargoNumber":"84645845"
            },
            {
               "cargoNumber":"84645852"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "reference":"LO0605275",
         "cargo":[
            {
               "cargoNumber":"84645869"
            },
            {
               "cargoNumber":"84645876"
            },
            {
               "cargoNumber":"84645883"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "reference":"LO0620192",
         "cargo":[
            {
               "cargoNumber":"84645890"
            },
            {
               "cargoNumber":"84645906"
            },
            {
               "cargoNumber":"84645913"
            },
            {
               "cargoNumber":"84645920"
            },
            {
               "cargoNumber":"84645937"
            },
            {
               "cargoNumber":"84645944"
            },
            {
               "cargoNumber":"84645951"
            },
            {
               "cargoNumber":"84645968"
            },
            {
               "cargoNumber":"84645975"
            },
            {
               "cargoNumber":"84645982"
            },
            {
               "cargoNumber":"84645999"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
}
```

Необходимо пройтись по всем массивам "orders" и привязать "cargos" относящиеся к ним.

```
            org.json.simple.JSONArray secondArray = (org.json.simple.JSONArray) jsonHead.get("orders");
            if (secondArray != null) {
                for (Object value : secondArray) {
                    JSONObject ordersObject = (JSONObject) value;
                    Orders ordersO = ordersService.getByReference(ordersObject.get("reference").toString());
                    if (ordersO == null) {
                        ordersO = new Orders();

                        if (ordersObject.get("reference") != null) {
                            ordersO.setOrderReference(ordersObject.get("reference").toString());
                        }
                        if (ordersObject.get("contentType") != null) {
                            ordersO.setContentType(ordersObject.get("contentType").toString());
                        }
                        if (ordersObject.get("supplierName") != null) {
                            ordersO.setSupplier(ordersObject.get("supplierName").toString());
                        }
                        if (ordersObject.get("orderType") != null) {
                            ordersO.setOrderType(ordersObject.get("orderType").toString());
                        }
                        if (ordersObject.get("consigneeName") != null) {
                            ordersO.setConsignee(ordersObject.get("consigneeName").toString());
                        }
                        if (ordersObject.get("comments") != null) {
                            ordersO.setComments(ordersObject.get("comments").toString());
                        }
                    } else {
                        if (ordersO.getInboundTrucks().size() != 0) {
                            if (ordersO.getInboundTrucks().get(0) != null) {
                                inboundTruck = ordersO.getInboundTrucks().get(0);
                            }
                        }
                        if (jsonHead.get("truckNumber") != null) {
                            inboundTruck.setTruckNumber(jsonHead.get("truckNumber").toString());
                        }
                        if (jsonHead.get("driverName") != null) {
                            inboundTruck.setDriverName(jsonHead.get("driverName").toString());
                        }
                    }

                    ordersList.clear();
                    cargoSet.clear();
                    ordersList.add(ordersO);

                    org.json.simple.JSONArray cargoArray = (org.json.simple.JSONArray) ordersObject.get("cargo");
                    if (ordersObject.get("cargo") != null) {
                        for (Object o : cargoArray) {
                            JSONObject ordersCargo = (JSONObject) o;
                            if (ordersCargo.get("cargoNumber") != null) {
                                Cargo cargoOrder = cargoService.getByNumber(ordersCargo.get("cargoNumber").toString());
                                if (cargoOrder != null) {
                                    logger.info(cargoOrder.getCargoNumber() + " ");

                                } else {
                                    cargoOrder = new Cargo();
                                    cargoOrder.setCargoNumber(ordersCargo.get("cargoNumber").toString());
                                    if (ordersObject.get("supplierName") != null) {
                                        cargoOrder.setSupplier(ordersObject.get("supplierName").toString());
                                    }
                                    if (ordersObject.get("consigneeName") != null) {
                                        cargoOrder.setConsignee(ordersObject.get("consigneeName").toString());
                                        cargoOrder.setCriteria(ordersObject.get("consigneeName").toString());
                                    }
                                    cargoOrder.setInboundTrucks(inbList);
                                    cargoOrder.setInBoundTruck(inboundTruck.getTruckNumber());
                                    cargoSet.add(cargoOrder);
                                }
                                ordersO.setCargos(cargoSet);
                                cargoService.addCargo(cargoOrder);
                                ordersService.addOrders(ordersO);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
                    inboundTruck.setCargos(cargoSet);
                }
```

Связь создается либо по массиву "cargos" в последнем массив  "orders" со всеми номерами заказов

Cargo.java:

```
@Entity
public class Cargo {
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "cargos", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Orders> orders;
--- getters and setters ---
}
```

Orders.java

```
@Entity
public class Orders {
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "OrdersCargo",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "orderId", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "cargoId", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<Cargo> cargos;
--- getters and setters ---
}
```

Comment: А Вы уверены в том что Вы валидный JSON указали? Как минимум то что я конкретно сейчас вижу в вопросе не является валидным JSON.

Comment: непонятно причем тут спринг и что там не так создаётся если вы вручную его(JSON) обходите

Comment: приложите реальный JSON чтобы на кофейной гуще не гадать

Comment: причем тут `spring`, `hibernate`, `jpa` и `many-to-many` вообще непонятно... и фразу `Связь создается либо по массиву "cargos" в последнем массив "orders" со всеми номерами заказов` тоже было бы неплохо расшифровать

Comment: добавил реальный JSON
Соглашусь, spring тут не при чем

Comment: да, так лучше. этот json валидный. минут через 10 посмотрю что тут не так

Comment: по поводу расшифровки - после прогона по этим двум циклам - создаются связи только у cargo из последнего массива orders, в данном примере из массива с референсом "LO0620192"

Comment: прогон по самому JSON проводится корректно вроде насколько я смог проверить. Во всяком случае все соответствует структуре JSON.

Comment: относительно связей...вы имеете в виду что они просто не сохраняются?

Comment: да, прогоняется ок, логи выводит тоже верные, но в общей таблице, где к Orders задается Cargo - логика нарушается и привязка происходит неверно либо вообще не происходит

Comment: уфф...  боюсь, чтобы дальше разобраться мне нужны модели `Cargo` и `Orders` (как минимум те части где они ссылаются друг на друга), а также методы `CargoService::addCargo()` и `OrdersService::addOrders()`

Comment: СТОП! нашел что меня смущает

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117761/discussion-between-kosha-and--).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Первое что меня смущает:**

`cargoSet`, Вы инициализируете его за пределами обработки самого списка и фактически используете ссылку на один и тот же набор.
Вы в каждый `Orders` вставляете ссылку на один и тот же `cargoSet`.
При этом при каждой итерации Вы их чистите.
Не надо так делать!

просто инициализируйте данный набор непосредственно перед обработкой массива `cargo`

```java
if (ordersObject.get("cargo") != null) {
    // инициализируем cargoSet
    Set<Cargo> cargoSet;
    if(ordersO.getCargos()){
        cargoSet = ordersO.getCargos();    
    }else{
        cargoSet = new HashSet();    
    }
    //и не придётся чистить потом
    for (Object o : cargoArray) {
        JSONObject ordersCargo = (JSONObject) o;
        if (ordersCargo.get("cargoNumber") != null) {
            //...
            ordersO.setCargos(cargoSet);                            
            cargoService.addCargo(cargoOrder);                            
            ordersService.addOrders(ordersO);
        }
   }
}
```

**Второе что меня смущает:**

Внимательно посмотрите на код сверху.
В нем удалена обработка `JSON`, но вложенность сохранилась оригинальная.

Вы выполняете эти три строки при обработке одного единственного `СargoOrder`

```
ordersO.setCargos(cargoSet);                            
cargoService.addCargo(cargoOrder);                            
ordersService.addOrders(ordersO);
```

т.е. каждый раз когда Вы обрабатываете `{"cargoNumber":"___________"}`, Вы пытаетесь добавить `Orders` и `Set<Cargo>`
Не надо так!
Все должно обрабатываться на своём уровне.

```
ordersO.setCargos(cargoSet);
```

Необходимо вынести за скобки после обработки всего массива `cargo`

```java
if (ordersObject.get("cargo") != null) {
   for (Object o : cargoArray) {
       //...
   }
   // ВОТ СЮДА!
   ordersO.setCargos(cargoSet);
}
```

А строку

```
ordersService.addOrders(ordersO);
```

необходимо перенести после обработки всего `Orders`

```java
if (secondArray != null) {
    for (Object value : secondArray) {
        JSONObject ordersObject = (JSONObject) value;
        Orders ordersO = ordersService.getByReference(ordersObject.get("reference").toString());
        // ...
        // ОБРАБОТКА ORDERS
        // ...
        
        // И перед самым закрытием 
        ordersService.addOrders(ordersO);
     }
}
```

А вот строка

```
cargoService.addCargo(cargoOrder);
```

остаётся на прежнем уровне.

**Третье что меня смущает:**

```
inboundTruck.setCargos(cargoSet);
```

Вы используете `cargoSet` за пределами цикла в котором Вы обрабатываете список `cargo` в конкретном `orders`

Я не знаю логики работы  `InboundTruck::setCargos()`, но одно могу сказать точно: так делать нельзя.

Вы и так каждый раз чистите этот набор в каждой итерации. И Вы установите в `inboundTruck` только последний обработанный набор, что очень напоминает описанное вами поведение.

В зависимости от логики вам нужно:

- либо спустить `inboundTruck.setCargos(cargoSet);` туда же где выполняется `ordersO.setCargos(cargoSet);`
- либо создайте второй `Set<Cargo>` в котором Вы будете агрегировать все `CargoOrder` во всем JSON'e и его уже добавляйте в `inboundTruck.setCargos(ultimateCargoSet);`